# does ree supports rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I found some article introduce about ree+passenger+nginx solution,and i want to know does the ree version supports rails3 ?

I found in ree offical site it said compatible with the 1.8.7 version

ree=Ruby Enterprise Edition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 3 supports 1.8.7 and 1.9.2, so as long as you're using the version of REE that is compatible with 1.8.7, it works perfectly.

(And as a little bonus, in our recent benchmarks REE was about ~20% faster than 1.8.7! Upgrading to 1.9.2 was even faster, but of course, that's not always an option.)